# libgdx making a touch event

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently following [this](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-libgdx-game-development-second-edition) book to create my libgdx game..

 So far, i have these classes to create my game :

- AbstractGameScreen.java - that Implements libgdx's Screen
- AbstractGameObject.java - that extends libgdx's Actor
- GamePlay.java - which is my game screen
- GameController.java - where i init my game objects
- GameRenderer.java - when i render all my objects
- Assets.java - a class that organizes my game assets
- Ring.java - an object in my game

And here is my code..

AbstractGameScreen

```
public abstract class AbstractGameScreen implements Screen {
    protected Game game;

    public AbstractGameScreen(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    public abstract void render(float deltaTime);
    public abstract void resize(int width, int height);
    public abstract void show();
    public abstract void hide();
    public abstract void pause();

    public void resume(String bg, String ring){
        Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager(), bg, ring);  // kosongin, jadinya default
    }

    public void dispose(){
        Assets.instance.dispose();
    }
}
```

AbstractGameObject

```
public abstract class AbstractGameObject extends Actor{ //implements EventListener{  //extends Sprite{
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 dimension;
    public Vector2 origin;
    public Vector2 scale;
    public float rotation;

    public AbstractGameObject(){
        position = new Vector2();
        dimension = new Vector2(1, 1);
        origin = new Vector2();
        scale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        rotation = 0;

    }

    public void update (float deltaTime){

    }

    public abstract void render(SpriteBatch batch);
}
```

GamePlay

```
public class GamePlay extends AbstractGameScreen implements InputProcessor{

    private GameController gameController;
    private GameRenderer gameRenderer;
    private String dummyBg, dummyRing;
    private boolean paused;

    // for touch purposes
    private static final int appWidth = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH_INT;
    private static final int appHeight = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT_INT;

    public GamePlay(Game game) {
        super(game);

        // still dummy.. nantinya ngambil dari database nya
        this.dummyBg = "bg-default";
        this.dummyRing = "ring-default";

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        if(!paused){
            gameController.update(deltaTime);
        }

        //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0x64 / 255.0f, 0x95 / 255.0f,0xed / 255.0f, 0xff / 255.0f);
        //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // render game nya
        gameRenderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gameRenderer.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager(), "bg-default", "ring-default");
        Gdx.app.log("GamePlay", "After show() method");

        gameController = new GameController(game);
        gameRenderer = new GameRenderer(gameController);
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        gameRenderer.dispose();
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        gameRenderer.dispose();
        Assets.instance.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        super.resume(this.dummyBg, this.dummyRing);
        //Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager(), this.dummyBg, this.dummyRing);

        paused = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return true;
    }

    // for touch purposes
    private float getCursorToModelX(int screenX, int cursorX) {
        return (((float)cursorX) * appWidth) / ((float)screenX); 
    }

    private float getCursorToModelY(int screenY, int cursorY) {
        return ((float)(screenY - cursorY)) * appHeight / ((float)screenY) ; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

GameController

```
public class GameController extends InputAdapter{
    // game objects
    public Array<Tiang> tiangs;
    public Array<Ring> rings;
    //private Game game;

    // game decorations
    public Background background;     public Sprite[] testSprite;
    private Game game;

    public GameController(Game game){
        this.game = game;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        // preparing variables
        rings = new Array<Ring>();
        tiangs = new Array<Tiang>();

        initObjects();
        initDecorations();
        initGui();
    }

    private void initObjects(){
        AbstractGameObject obj = null;
        obj = new Ring(1, "default");

        obj.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //super.clicked(event, x, y);
                Gdx.app.log("tag", "test clisk");
            }
        });

        rings.add((Ring)obj);
    }

    private void initDecorations(){

    }

    private void initGui(){

    }

    private void handleInput(float deltatime){

    }

    public void update(float deltaTime){
        //if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        //  Gdx.app.log("update", "screen touched");
        //}
    }
}
```

GameRenderer

```
public class GameRenderer implements Disposable{

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private GameController controller;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    public GameRenderer(GameController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);  //diambil dari class "Constants" (di package util)
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        camera.update();
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height){
        camera.viewportWidth = (Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT / height) * width;
        camera.update();
    }

    public void render(){
        renderGui();
        renderDecorations();
        renderObjects();
    }

    private void renderGui(){

    }

    private void renderDecorations(){

    }

    private void renderObjects(){
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();

        for(Ring rings : controller.rings){
            rings.render(batch);
        }

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Assets

```
public class Assets implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener{
    public static final String TAG = Assets.class.getName();
    public static final Assets instance = new Assets();

    private AssetManager assetManager;

    // inner class objects
    public AssetTiang tiang;
    public AssetBackgroud bg;
    public AssetTombol tombol;
    public AssetTombolBg tombolBg;
    public AssetRing ring;

    //singleton pattern, buat mencegah instansiasi dari class yang lain
    private Assets(){}

    //public void init(AssetManager assetManager){
    public void init(AssetManager assetManager, String jenisBg, String jenisRing){
        this.assetManager = assetManager;
        assetManager.setErrorListener(this);

        //load texture atlas yang udah dibikin pake TexturePacker nya (liat ebook page 167) 
        assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS, TextureAtlas.class);
        assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_DECORATION, TextureAtlas.class);
        assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_GUI, TextureAtlas.class);

        // inner class objects
        tiang = new AssetTiang(atlasObject);
        bg = new AssetBackgroud(atlasDecoration, jenisBg);
        tombol = new AssetTombol(atlasGui);
        tombolBg = new AssetTombolBg(atlasDecoration);
        ring = new AssetRing(atlasObject, jenisRing);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(AssetDescriptor asset, Throwable throwable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        assetManager.dispose();
    }

    public class AssetRing{
        public final AtlasRegion ring;

        // jenis ring dimasukin disini, karena jenis ring bisa diganti-ganti sesuai yang dipilih
        public AssetRing(TextureAtlas atlas, String jenisRing){
            if(!jenisRing.equals("")){
                ring = atlas.findRegion(jenisRing);
            }
            else{
                ring = atlas.findRegion("ring-default");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, Ring (Object)

```
public class Ring extends AbstractGameObject{
    private TextureRegion ringOverLay;
    private float length;

    // jenis ring nya
    public String jenis;

    public Ring(float length, String jenis){
        init();

        setLength(length);
        setJenis(jenis);
    }

    // getters
    public float getLength(){
        return this.length;
    }

    public String getJenis(){
        return this.jenis;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    // setters
    public void setLength(float length){
        this.length = length;
        dimension.set(5.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void setJenis(String jenis){
        this.jenis = jenis;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y){
        position.set(x, y);
    }

    private void init(){
        ringOverLay = Assets.instance.ring.ring;  // Assets.instance.namaobjek.atlasregion

        origin.x = dimension.x/2;  // -dimension.x/2;
        origin.y = dimension.y/2;

        position.x = -5.0f;
        position.y = -2.5f;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        TextureRegion reg = null;
        reg = ringOverLay;

        batch.draw(reg.getTexture(), position.x, position.y, origin.x, origin.y, dimension.x, dimension.y, scale.x, scale.y, rotation, reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), reg.getRegionWidth(), reg.getRegionHeight(), false, false);
    }

}
```

So what's the problem? Okay, the problem is i cannot make the Ring (game object) become clickable.. the Ring is extending AbstractGameObject (which is Actor), and, in the GameController i've add a `ClickListener` to the Ring object, but the object still unclickable..

Please, anyone tell me what's my mistake?

Comment: It is easier to answer questions when there is a minimal description of the issue. Too much code makes it that much harder to find what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're using your `Actor` (in your case, the `Ring`) incorrectly: `Actors` are part of [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d), and as such must follow precise rules to work correctly.

To answer your question more specifically, `Ring` needs to be added to a `Stage` which itself is an `InputProcessor`. The `Stage` is responsible to distribute the input events (such as touch events) to the its `Actors`. Without defining a `Stage` your `Actors` will not respond to any input events.

Read up on `Scene2d` from the link above. This [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPIeERAm2ao) is also helpful.